# Using variable to unwrap object

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dictionary and need to get content out of the first item. Looks like this:

```
{
  some_object_key: {
     -- the goodness I need to get at
  },
  another_object_key: {
     -- don't really need this one, first one is fine
  },
}
```

That key is a generated _id, so in order to unwrap I'm grabbing the key as a variable. But obviously when you use the variable to unwrap it just tries to use the variable name.

```
select 
to_char(GET(OBJECT_KEYS(projects),0)) as first_object_key
, projects:first_object_key as first_object
FROM table

-- just tries to unwrap "first_object_key" from the dictionary
```

What's the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [OBJECT_PICK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_pick):

```
SELECT OBJECT_KEYS(projects)[0] as first_object_key
      ,OBJECT_PICK(projects,first_object_key)  as first_object
FROM tab;
```

For input data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(projects OBJECT)
AS
SELECT '{
  some_object_key: {key: 1
  },
  another_object_key: {key: 2
  },
}';
```

Output:

| FIRST_OBJECT_KEY | FIRST_OBJECT |
| --- | --- |
| "another_object_key" | { "another_object_key": { "key": 2 } } |

---

Alternatively using `FLATTEN`:

```
SELECT s.key, s.value
FROM tab
,TABLE(FLATTEN(tab.projects)) as s
WHERE s.key = OBJECT_KEYS(projects)[0];
```

Output:

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| another_object_key | { "key": 2 } |

Comment: Hero. Flatten worked great. This also got me started again and I found GET, which seems to work as well https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get